# Disable encryption with :X in vim

Tags: vim

I find myself hitting `:X` when I mean to type `:x`

Is there a way to disable `:X` as encryption so that typing `:X` in vim has no effect?

I assume there is a command that can be placed in the .vimrc file?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a somewhat standard way of using `cnoreabbrev`/`cnoremap` for this: before replacing `X` with `x` check whether it is the only character on the command-line:

```
cnoremap <expr> X (getcmdtype() is# ':' && empty(getcmdline())) ? 'x' : 'X'
```

or

```
cnoreabbrev <expr> X (getcmdtype() is# ':' && getcmdline() is# 'X') ? 'x' : 'X'
```

. The difference is that first will prevent you from typing `:Xfoo` (will translate into `:xfoo`), second will not, but will prevent from typing `:X!` (will translate into `:x!` which indeed makes sense unlike `:X!`).

There is exactly no difference for searching (`/X` is fine), `input()` prompt and so on and no difference if typed `X` is not the first one.

Comment: how do I make the second one not prevent me from typing `:X!` ?

Comment: @BPm Why do you ask? Running `:X!` throws “E477: No ! allowed”, redefining `:X` is also not possible. If you ask for remapping something other then `X` use additional `getchar(1) isnot char2nr('!')` condition.

Comment: I asked because I tend to type `:W` by mistake but another plugin has a command `:W!`. I'll try the additional condition. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Use `:cnoreabbrev` to override `:X` with the same functionality as `:x`:

```
cnoreabbrev X x
```

`:cnoreabbrev` is preferred to `:cabbrev` since `:x` might already be remapped to something else.

Note that using `cabbrev` in general will affect all single-letter words `X` in the command line, e.g. `:X X` will translate to `:x x`, probably not what's intended. See @ZyX's answer for a fix to this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `:cmap` to map X into x, but there are side effects, like not being able to use the letter X anywhere

```
:cmap X x
```

For a slightly less intrusive version

```
:cmap X^M x^M
```

which will only map X to x when you hit enter immediately afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

The [cmdalias.vim - Create aliases for Vim commands](http://www.vim.org/script.php?script_id=746) plugin provides a more robust implementation of ZyX's answer. If you don't mind installing a plugin, you get a comfortable and extensible way to define abbreviations:

```
:Alias X x
```