# Replacing in vim from current line by simple command

Tags: vim, replace, command

I'm very often replacing from current line in vim with command: ":,$s/old/new/gc". Is there any way to make command simpler? Something like this: ":z/old/new".

Answer (score 1):

You can define a custom `:Z` (sorry, it has to be uppercase) command:

```
:command! -nargs=1 Z .,$s<args>/gc
```

Comment: Built-in commands start with lowercase ones. You could work around that with a `:cmap` or the cmdalias plugin, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17792177/disable-encryption-with-x-in-vim).